# Apple Automator take screen capture and save to user-specified location

Tags: applescript, automator

So, I'm trying to use Automator under Mac OS Yosemite to create a service to allow a user to take a screenshot and save it to a location they specify, through some sort of "Save As" dialog.  It seemed like it should be easy, but for some reason I'm running into difficulty with it.  The screenshot component is easy, using the "Take Screenshot" action in Automator, but it's the saving it to a custom location that's causing me problems.

After trying a few different approaches, it seemed the easiest thing to do was to save the screenshot to a fixed directory/filename from within the "Take Screenshot" action, and then (using AppleScript) rename it in that directory, and move it to the user-specified target directory.  So, I added a "Run AppleScript" action to my service.  In it, I generate the dialog to choose a file name/path, using the `choose file name` command in AppleScript.  I'm trying to split up the file name from the path, so that I can rename the file I save in "Take Screenshot," and then move it to the path that I'd like to save it at.  I can get the full path, but am having problems just getting the filename from the path—and I've tried a variety of suggestions from what I've seen online.  In my screenshot, the error shown was from attempting to do

I'm not set by any means on this flow, so if anyone has any better suggestions on how to do what I'm trying to do, by all means please let me know.  Otherwise, if someone's able to just tell me how I can extract the filename from the path (and also if there's some special way you have to use that string to rename the file) that'd be great!

[image: Screenshot of Automator service]

AppleScript code pictured in screenshot:

```
on run {parameters}
    set thePath to (choose file name with prompt "Where would you like to save your file?")
    tell application "Finder"
        display dialog thePath as string
    end tell
    set UnixPath to POSIX path of (thePath as text)
    display dialog UnixPath
end run
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

`set basePath to POSIX path of (parent of (thePath) as string)`

Thanks for checking it out!

Comment: Check out the templates that Script-Editor has in it's "File" menu, try  "Droplets => Droplet with settable properties" / it includes code that shows how to get the name /extension for a file path. Also, check out "man screencapture" in a Terminal.app window. "screencapture" does all the real work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way would be to use the command line tool "screencapture". It has many options you can choose. See its man page. Here's an example that you can run as an applescript directly or you could put this inside an applescript automator action if you want.

Good luck.

```
set thePath to (choose file name with prompt "Where would you like to save your file?")
do shell script "screencapture -mx -T1 " & quoted form of (POSIX path of thePath & ".png")
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly! Not sure why Apple doesn't make this easier to do with pure Automator actions, unless I was missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a Folder action in Automator. Choose Desktop. Add Find Finder objects (search: Desktop). Add Move Finder Object and choose your preferred destination. This will automatically move all your screenshots.